# SPField custom attributes in schema

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xsd, spfield

I'm trying to decide whether it is possible to store custom attributes in a SPField's schema XML.

If you look at the .xsd for the 'Field' element in SharePoint, there are a slew of attributes. The last one in the attribute list is `<xs:anyAttribute>`. This elements purpose is to allow it be extended. This obviously leads me to believe it is possible to store custom attributes. However, I cannot find any documentation on this.

Anyone have any experience with this, or seen documentation saying yay or nay on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right you can have custom Attributes to the SPField,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="Property1">ConfigurableURL</Field>
    <Field Name="Property2">Value2</Field>
    <PropertySchema>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="CustomAttributeOne" DisplayName="CustomAttributeOneDisplay" Type="Text"></Field>
      </Fields>
    </PropertySchema>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

You can find more information about the subject at the below links

[Link1](http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2009/01/23/customizing-the-rendering-of-a-custom-spfield.aspx)

[Link2](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/05/12/defining-custom-properies-of-sharepoint-fields/)

[Link3](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/02/23/regular-expression-validated-custom-spfield.aspx)